# Use of alloc_page return value

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to know the use of the return value of `alloc_page`, it allocates page and returns an instance of `struct page` to represent the start of the reserved block. However, I have no clue how to use that reserved page after allocation. I have trouble understanding that stuff, `kmalloc` is very simple, we just can allocate memory into a `char *buf` for example, but this kernel functions return a structure and I have no clue how to use it for my needs.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct page *p;

static int __init sys_module_init(void)
{
    p = alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL);

    pr_info(KBUILD_MODNAME ": Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit sys_module_exit(void)
{
    __free_page(p);
    
    pr_info(KBUILD_MODNAME ": Bye, World!\n");
}

module_init(sys_module_init);
module_exit(sys_module_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("StackOverflow");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alloc_page()` is lower level than `kmalloc()`. If the `struct page` were coming from a user space program, you'd need to first map it to kernel address space using `kmap()`. But since you're allocating kernel memory with `GFP_KERNEL`, then you can just take the page struct and then convert it to its virtual address using `page_address()`. Then you can use the address in a function like `memcpy()` to write data to it. I'm sure there are other ways to write/read from the page including things like casting the memory to different types, but then you probably need to do the memory management yourself. All depends what specifically you want to do with the page.

Comment: Okay thank you. One thing I don't understand is why would `alloc_page` return a structure if we have no use with it at all? Why not just return the memory address?

Comment: Different uses in the kernel. Sometimes you want the `struct page` so you can modify the flags in the struct, other times you want the address, which is basically why `kmalloc` exists. It's an easier way to get memory readily available with less low-level work to get it set up.

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I understand a lot now.

Comment: Great! You're welcome. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.